# Virt manager macvtap guest interface settings

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to configure KVM guest with macvtap network on eth2 of the host machine. 
eth2 on host have static public ip address and gateway.

On the quest machine i see the interface is named ens9 with MAC same as the macvtap0 on host.
`ifup ens9` outputs unknown interface ens9.

If i add

```
auto ens9
iface ens9 inet dhcp
```

it is not able to obtain IP address.
If i add the same IP as host as static it does not have internet connection (host have connection through eth2)

What config should i enter in /etc/network/interfaces of guest to get it connected to the internet?
My idea is having multiple virtual machines having their own public IP addresses.